# how to add legend(at X and Y axis) to the chart

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to add  to my chart at the axis X and Y to what they refers
eg: add number of issues and project

**Current chart**
[image]

**Required chart**
[image]

Comment: Please show an example of how the chart currently looks (label it **Current**) and *exactly* how you want the chart to look (label it **Required**).

Comment: @Dave Jarvis,I have updated my post

Comment: Can you not use Static Text above (and to the left), as well as Static Text below (and to the far right) of the chart, in the same band (e.g., the Summary Band)?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis ,I have add Static Text to show what I need, I didn't added them on the chart but manually using paint

Answer (score 1):

I am using JasperReports 5.6.1.

In bar plot section (of the `.jrxml` file) I put :

```
<barPlot isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
<plot>
    <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#00FF00" />
</plot>

<categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$P{xAxisLabel}]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
<categoryAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat>
        <labelFont>
            <font size="12" isBold="true" />
        </labelFont>
    </axisFormat>
</categoryAxisFormat>
<valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["[ persons ]"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat>
        <labelFont>
            <font size="12" isBold="true" />
        </labelFont>
    </axisFormat>
</valueAxisFormat>
</barPlot>
```

I have both axis labelled, however label for `x` axis is below `x` axis and label for `y` axis is left to the `y` axis (a little bit different then in your screen).

In `x` axis case I have used report parameter. In both axis labels I have used bold font for labels to be more readable.